# Kubernetes: taints and toleration

Tags: kubernetes

We use kubernetes with aws cloud and for one node I applied taints using the `kubectl` command. When I restart that node, taints are lost.

So I wanted to know, do kubernetes taints persist or not?

Answer (score 0):

Taints applied to a node via `kubectl` will not persist a reboot, but depending on your Kubernetes install method, etc, you can manually register a node with the `--register-with-taints` flag to add taints that should persist the restarts.

[Kubernetes Node Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#self-registration-of-nodes)